# Using Marketing API to fetch AdInsights with breakdown hourly, but no hourly data returned

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Marketing API v7.0  (java libs)

I am attempting to pull hourly metric data but the returned report does not contain hourly information. Here is  some pseudo code so you can see how I'm trying to get it:

```
AdAccount.APIRequestGetInsightsAsync insightsRequest = new AdAccount(ac.getId(), context).getInsightsAsync();
insightsRequest.setLevel( AdsInsights.EnumLevel.VALUE_ADSET );
insightsRequest.setBreakdowns(Arrays.asList(AdsInsights.EnumBreakdowns.VALUE_HOURLY_STATS_AGGREGATED_BY_AUDIENCE_TIME_ZONE));
// fields == "adset_id","campaign_id","impressions","inline_link_clicks","spend,action_values","actions","date_start"
insightsRequest.requestFields( Arrays.asList(fields) );
AdReportRun report = insightsRequest.execute();
```

I'm expecting data returned in this report to include hourly info,  something like this:

```
....
{
"impressions": "172",
"date_start": "2020-06-23",
"date_stop": "2020-06-23",
"hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone": "01:00:00 - 01:59:59"
...
}
....
```

However, the data I get back looks like this

```
....
{
"impressions": "172",
"date_start": "2020-06-23",
"date_stop": "2020-06-23",
...
}
....
```

which is to say, the  "hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone": "01:00:00 - 01:59:59" data is never present in the json.  As such I have no hourly information.

Any insight as to why this might be, or what I may be doing incorrectly would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. The problem was that the **AdsInsights** class in the

```
facebook-java-business-sdk.7.0.1
```

java lib is missing the following data members:

```
@SerializedName("hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone") 
private String mHourlyStatsAggregatedByAdvertiserTimeZone = null; 

@SerializedName("hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone") 
private String mHourlyStatsAggregatedByAudienceTimeZone = null;
```

Apparently, the last time these fields were present was in the 6.0.0 version of the same lib. I checked the change logs and there is no indication that these fields have been deprecated or removed so this is almost certainly an oversight of some sort.

To whomever can update the latest java jdk libs, please restore these fields as well as the **product_id** data member which is also missing. Thanks.